# Cumsum function and n% of records in a column that contributing the most

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset showing the minutes usage of some individuals (dummy data for two days in below). My aim is to first flag individual that generate the most (50% of total usage per day) and then calculate what % of total usage is generated by those (already flagged) individuals:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~date,         ~id, ~usage,
  20191101, "405162-aa",      5,
  20191102, "504653-ab",     22,
  20191102, "900232-aa",      1,
  20191102, "504694-aa",      12,
  20191101, "400304-aa",      42,
  20191101, "401605-aa",      2,
  20191102, "900029-aa",      31,
  20191102, "400090-aa",      25,
  20191102, "403004-aa",      33,
  20191102, "900222-ab",      2,
  20191101, "403967-aa",      11,
  20191102, "400304-aa",      52,
  20191101, "404308-aa",      200,
  20191102, "403898-aa",      2,
  20191101, "158159-aa",      24,
  20191102, "700805-aa",      2,
  20191102, "900245-ab",      24,
  20191101, "501486-aa",      2,
  20191101, "400215-ab",      210,
  20191101, "504379-aa",      26,
  20191102, "900222-aa",      400,
  20191101, "109700-aa",      46,
  20191101, "142173-aa",     14,
  20191101, "400586-aa",      22,
  20191101, "401605-aa",      322
  )
```

Ex: Looking at the dummy dataset for 20191101 , the cumulative sum is 926 minutes , user 400215-ab with 210 mins and user401605-aa with 324 mins are users that generated the most ( flag individuals ) and these two individuals generated almost 58% of total usage on 20191101.

Here is my try, it is working, however I am wondering is there any other alternative/better way

```
library(tidyverse)

    df %>%
    group_by(date, id) %>%
      summarise(total_min = sum(usage)) %>%
      arrange(date,total_min) %>%
      mutate(#cumulative sum minutes
        cumsum = cumsum(total_min),
        # Flag user whom generate 50% of usage
        case = cumsum <= (sum(total_min) * 0.50)) %>%  
      filter(case == FALSE) %>%
      group_by(date) %>% 
      mutate( max_cumsum = max(cumsum)) %>% 
      select(-case , -cumsum  ) %>% 
      group_by(date) %>%
      summarise( percentage = sum(total_min)/mean(max_cumsum) )
```

I would like to have this output at the end for 20191110:

```
      date flag_individual  total_usage  cumsum_day  contribution_percentage
     <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 20191101    2                 534         926        0.577
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative option: I would recommend keeping data in a long(-ish) format. This may make it easier for further downstream processing.

Something like this:

```
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(date, id) %>%
    summarise(sum_usage = sum(usage)) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(total_usage = sum(sum_usage)) %>%
    arrange(date, desc(sum_usage)) %>%
    top_n(which.max(cumsum(sum_usage) / total_usage > 0.5), sum_usage) %>%
    ungroup()
df2
## A tibble: 3 x 4
## Groups:   date [2]
#      date id        sum_usage total_usage
#     <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 20191101 401605-aa       324         926
#2 20191101 400215-ab       210         926
#3 20191102 900222-aa       400         606
```

You *could* bring `df2` into a form mirroring your expected output

```
df2 %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(
        flag_individual = n(),
        sum_usage = sum(sum_usage),
        total_usage = first(total_usage),
        contribution_fraction = sum_usage / total_usage)
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#      date flag_individual sum_usage total_usage contribution_fraction
#     <dbl>           <int>     <dbl>       <dbl>                 <dbl>
#1 20191101               2       534         926                 0.577
#2 20191102               1       400         606                 0.660
```

A minor nitpick;-) Please note that I've changed the names of the summary output columns, because

- what you call `total_usage` is really the sum of `usage` for the top users;
- what you call `cumsum_day` is really the total `usage`, and
- what you call `contribution_percentage` is really the the fractional contribution of the top users.

Answer (score 1):

We can arrange in descending order then the select individuals who contribute .50 or more

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
arrange(date,-usage) %>% 
group_by(date) %>% 
mutate(total_usage = cumsum(usage), 
       cumsum_day = sum(usage, na.rm = TRUE),
       contribution_percentage = total_usage/cumsum_day, 
       flag_individual = which(contribution_percentage>.5)[1]) %>%  
filter(row_number()==flag_individual) %>%
#filter(between(row_number(), 1, flag_individual)) %>% 
select(-id, -usage)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   date [2]
      date usage total_usage cumsum_day contribution_percentage flag_individual
     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>                   <dbl>           <int>
1 20191101   210         532        926                   0.575               2
2 20191102   400         400        606                   0.660               1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess we shouldn't keep id column here ,  since only show one per date, no?

Comment: I thought you may need id for later analysis, if not just do `select(-id)`